Is it possible to open the information in the OMF File (Open Media Framework) in Python or other Language?
I want to make a function to organize the information of the track by reading the information in the OMF file.
Is there a library or something where I can read the information in the omf file from the code?
I don't have any clue, so I need a clue.
I've looked it up in many ways, but I don't think I've ever read an omf file. Am I wrong with the definition of an omf file?

OMF files contain various information, so make sure to explore the specific data you need within the file.
you can use omf lib
pip install omf

Alternatively, you can clone the GitHub repository and install from there:
git clone https://github.com/gmggroup/omf.git
cd omf
pip install -e .

After doing these things, the following code will help you
import omf

reader = omf.OMFReader('your_omf_file.omf')
project = reader.get_project()

uids_to_import = [element.uid for element in project.elements if isinstance(element, omf.PointSetElement)]
filtered_project = reader.get_project(uids_to_import)


No.. Open Mining Format. It is Open Media Framework
